# HTML Portfolio with filter and fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is this: I have created a portfolio on the website, but I want that when I go on the portfolio section through the navbar menu, the filter button is already active, I don't want all the image on the screen. This is my code for the filter and for the fancybox.

This is the code for the button and for the filter

```
<button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="impiantistica">Impiantistica</button>
```

This is the code for the fancybox

```
  <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter impiantistica" >
     <img src="immagini/servizi/impiantistica-01.jpg" class="img-responsive fancybox round-5" href="immagini/servizi/impiantistica-01.jpg" data-fancybox-group="Impiantistica" width="95%">
  </div>
```

This is the portfolio's link https://adrgeneralcontract.com/new/portfolio.html

Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css file

```
.gallery_product { display: none; }
.gallery_product.impiantistica { display: block; }
```